# Excel crashes after code runs on files that are connected to a Jedox server

Tags: excel, vba

I've written a macro to open all xlsx files from a provided folder path, change one specific worksheet's cell value and save it as a new file in a different provided folder path.

The macro does what I want.

I run this macro on files that are connected to a Jedox server.

After this code runs, the original workbook that I run the macro from crashes.

```vb
Function GetUNCLateBound(ByVal strMappedDrive As String) As String

    Dim objFso As Object
    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim strDrive As String
    Dim strShare As String

    'Separate the mapped letter from any following sub-folders
    strDrive = objFso.GetDriveName(strMappedDrive)

    'Find the UNC share name from the mapped letter
    strShare = objFso.Drives(strDrive & "\").ShareName

    'The Replace function allows for sub-folders of the mapped drive
    GetUNCLateBound = Replace(strMappedDrive, strDrive, strShare)

    Set objFso = Nothing 'Destroy the object

End Function

Sub UpdateConnection()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wbNew As Workbook
    Dim vDevConName As Range
    Dim vProdConName As Range
    Dim vProdFolder As Range
    Dim vDevFolder As Range
    Dim vWBFromPath As String
    Dim vWBToPath As String

    ' Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set vDevConName = wb.Names("rngDevConnection").RefersToRange
    Set vProdConName = wb.Names("rngProdConnection").RefersToRange
    Set vDevFolder = wb.Names("rngDevFolder").RefersToRange
    Set vProdFolder = wb.Names("rngProdFolder").RefersToRange

    vWBToPath = GetUNCLateBound(wb.Path) & "\" & vProdFolder & "\"
    If Dir(vWBToPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir vWBToPath
    End If

    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path
    vWBFromPath = GetUNCLateBound(wb.Path) & "\" & vDevFolder & "\"

    'In Case of Cancel
    myPath = vWBFromPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xls*"

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)
    Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wbNew = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

        'Change cell B2 to provided PROD connection name
        With wbNew.Sheets("Params").Range("B2")
            .Value = vProdConName.Value
            .Calculate
            .Calculate
        End With

        'Suppresses warning about overwriting files
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

        wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=vWBToPath & myFile, FileFormat:=51
        wbNew.Close SaveChanges:=True

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Activate the original workbook
    wb.Activate

    'Message Box when tasks are completed
    MsgBox "Task Complete!"

ResetSettings:
    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Crashes - How? When?

Comment: @topsail it crashes after its finished running.  the original workbook activates, my cursor spins and spins and then the original workbook eventually crashes and reopens.

Comment: Technically, since the code is finished running, your problem may have nothing to do with this code. Just saying.

Comment: @topsail thats my thought as well.  Im running this macro on files that are connected to a Jedox server and i've had trouble with VBA and Jedox in the past.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced `.Calculate` with `Application.Run ("PALO.CALCSHEET")`.
Apparently when working with an Excel file with an active jedox connection, `.Calculate` is not sufficient.

old:

```vb
With wbNew.Sheets("Params").Range("B2")
    .Value = vProdConName.Value
    .Calculate
    .Calculate
End With
```

new:

```vb
With wbNew.Sheets("Params").Range("B2")
    .Value = vProdConName.Value
    Application.Run ("PALO.CALCSHEET")
    Application.Run ("PALO.CALCSHEET")
End With
```